# How to get a reference to the jar file produced by Gradle build?

Tags: build, gradle

I need to sign a jar after the jar task is being done in gradle. I have a need to reference the produced jar file from the build, and I can recreate the jar file, but I really look for a property that does this for me.

Here is how I've done it:

```
jar.doLast {
  jarfile = project.libsDir.path + File.separator + project.Name + '-' + project.version + '.jar'
  ant.signJar(jar: jarfile, ....
}
```

Is there a property which can be used instead of the long "path calculation"?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`jar.archivePath` returns a file object pointing to the generated jar file.

Update: `jar.archivePath` is deprecated. Look at `.archiveFile` instead.

Comment: hmmmmm, why is it that doesn't show up when I type in "gradle properties".  I thought that would show all properties :(.

Comment: jar.archivePath is not a gradle property... that is, it is not defined in a properties file or on the command line (see http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html ).  `jar` is a task name and `archivePath` is a property of that task.

Comment: I had this problem almost 5 years ago and I would be surprised if Gradle hasn't changes anything since then, but I haven't used Gradle in a long time. If anyone writes a new answer I will gladly set it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Your answer is still correct as of Gradle 2.3: http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html

Comment: jar.archivePath is deprecated now, use `.archiveFile` instead

Comment: to be more precise, use: `.archiveFile.get().asFile` as replacement.